# Codeigniter - Memory exhausted

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working with Codeigniter and a MSSQL database connection. Sometimes, I get this error message :

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 139817425963032 bytes) in Unknown on line 0.

I'm overwhelmed by the idea that the application needs **139817425963032 bytes** (130 Tb) to work.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: It's almost definitely something in your code, something you wrote. Done any debugging? Can you at least narrow down the source of the problem? Some sort of recursion mistake perhaps?

Comment: This is not enough information, we need to see your code

Comment: *"...in Unknown on line 0."* ...weird - that isn't a very helpful error message is it?

Comment: We're using a own made MSSQL class that work perfectly outside of Codeigniter. It's been almost 2 months that we're working on this project. But since 3 or 4 days, we're having this problem and we didn't on the core of the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically caused by operations which result in recursion, logging (e.g. `var_dump`) large chunks of data (like an array of models), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a 64-bit pointer (only 48 bits are used for virtual address on modern x86-64) got passed to malloc().

Must be a bug in some extension, if it only happens sometimes, it could be e.g. a buffer overflow. If it happens all the time, it out to be regular bug.